# How to upsample xarray by seconds and include bounding hours

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a `xarray.DataArray` with a coordinate like

```py
ary["time"] = [
    "2000-01-01T03:04:05",  # leading records are missing,
    "2000-01-01T03:04:06",
    "2000-01-01T03:04:08",  # some medium records are missing,
    "2000-01-01T03:04:09",
    "2000-01-01T03:04:11",
    ...
    "2000-01-01T06:54:02",
    "2000-01-01T06:54:03"   # and trailing records are missing.
]
```

and want to re-index to

```py
ary["time"] = [
    "2000-01-01T03:00:00",
    "2000-01-01T03:00:01",
    "2000-01-01T03:00:02",
    ...
    "2000-01-01T03:04:06",
    "2000-01-01T03:04:07",
    "2000-01-01T03:04:08",
    "2000-01-01T03:04:09",
    ...
    "2000-01-01T06:59:57",
    "2000-01-01T06:59:58",
    "2000-01-01T06:59:59"
]
```

and set *NaN* at all missing records.

I found `ary = ary.resample(time="1S").asfreq()` but it only inserts medium records.

How can I indicate that left and right bounds are every hours? (or minutes or days?)

---

Sample (taken from [gist](https://gist.github.com/VillSnow/495997fa2cbda11f510929c80593991b)):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr


def make_ary():
    time = []
    for i in range(300, 14000):
        if i % 3 != 2 and i % 5 != 2:
            time.append(datetime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0) + timedelta(seconds=i))

    data = np.random.rand(len(time))
    return xr.DataArray(data=data, coords=[("time", time)], dims=["time"])


def make_expected():
    expected = []
    for i in range(0, 4*60*60):
        expected.append(
            datetime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0) + timedelta(seconds=i)
        )
    return pd.to_datetime(np.array(expected))


def make_not_expected():
    '''
    result of 'inserts medium records'
    '''
    not_expected = []
    for i in range(300, 14000):
        not_expected.append(
            datetime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0) + timedelta(seconds=i)
        )
    return pd.to_datetime(np.array(not_expected))


def resample(ary):
    return ary.resample(time="1S").asfreq()


def main():
    ary = make_ary()
    expected = make_expected()
    not_expected = make_not_expected()

    print(np.array_equal(ary["time"].values, expected))  # False

    ary = resample(ary)
    print(np.array_equal(ary["time"], expected))      # False
    print(np.array_equal(ary["time"], not_expected))  # True, but not expected


main()
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? And what do you mean by "it only inserts medium records"?

Comment: Now I tried to add sample code but "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." occurs.

Comment: @Val any way, `ary.resample(time="1S").asfreq()` results [03:04:05, 03:04:06, ..., 06:54:03]. I mean it insert medium records: missing medium records are inserted. but I need [03:00:00, 03:00:01, ..., 06:59:59] because I need missing leading and trailing records too.

Comment: if you edit your original question, you should be able to add some example code - best if you can create the `ary` object which replicates the issues you have.

Comment: @Val I GOT "IT LOOKS LIKE YOUR POST IS MOSTLY CODE; PLEASE ADD SOME MORE DETAILS" AND WARE NOT ABLE TO COMPLETE EDITING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use DataArray.reindex ([Documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex.html))

In this scenario particularly, `DataArray.reindex` might be a better choice.

In the code sample below, the date range of the target array is specified with `date_range` (note that the parameter `closed` is set to `"left"` as we don't want the range to include `"2000-01-01T07:00:00"`.

```
start_time = "2000-01-01T03:00:00"
end_time = "2000-01-01T07:00:00"
new_ary = ary.reindex(time=pd.date_range(start=start_time,end=end_time,freq="1S",closed='left'))
print(ary)
```

This gives the following output:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 14400)>
array(['2000-01-01T03:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-01T03:00:01.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T03:00:02.000000000', ..., '2000-01-01T06:59:57.000000000',
       '2000-01-01T06:59:58.000000000', '2000-01-01T06:59:59.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T03:00:00 ... 2000-01-01T06:59:59
```

---

By default, `reindex` fills missing values with *NaN*. The outputs for the test code below demonstrates that missing values between `"2000-01-01T03:08:06"` and `"2000-01-01T03:08:09"` are set to *NaN* for the new array.

```
print(ary[100:102])
# Non NaN values start from index 300 for new_ary
print(new_ary[486:490])
```

Outputs:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 2)>
array([0.25910861, 0.07897777])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T03:08:06 2000-01-01T03:08:09
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([0.25910861,        nan,        nan, 0.07897777])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T03:08:06 ... 2000-01-01T03:08:09
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but It was much faster than resample. thank you

Comment: @v.snow I think this has something to do with the behavior of how you deal with missing values. While `reindex` simply fills NaN for missing values, `resample` applies `asfreq` , which behaves similarly, but requires a lot more computations.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want, is to just append a `NaN` pad to the beginning and end with the respective timestamp, and then just use `resample`:

```py
start_timestamp = "2000-01-01T03:00:00"
stop_timestamp = "2000-01-01T06:59:59"

ary2 = xr.concat([
    xr.DataArray(data=[np.nan], coords=[("time", pd.date_range(start=start_timestamp, freq="1S", periods=1))], dims=["time"]),
    ary,
    xr.DataArray(data=[np.nan], coords=[("time", pd.date_range(start=stop_timestamp, freq="1S", periods=1))], dims=["time"])
], dim="time").resample(time="1s").asfreq()
```

giving you:

```py
print(ary2.time)

# <xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 14400)>
# array(['2000-01-01T03:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-01T03:00:01.000000000',
#        '2000-01-01T03:00:02.000000000', ..., '2000-01-01T06:59:57.000000000',
#        '2000-01-01T06:59:58.000000000', '2000-01-01T06:59:59.000000000'],
#       dtype='datetime64[ns]')
# Coordinates:
#   * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T03:00:00 ... 2000-01-01T06:59:59
```

Comment: I did not checked as accepted but better when I have to use any method other than *asfreq*